# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded:

Tags: python, oracle, connection

**Following are the versions installed**:

- **CX_Oracle**: cx_Oracle-6.4.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
- **Python Version**:  [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- **Oracle version**: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

**Am executing the following**:

```
import cx_Oracle
connection = cx_Oracle.connect("username", "password", "database IP")
cursor = connection.cursor()
querystring = "select * from table_name"
cursor.execute(querystring)
```

**Getting error**:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: 64-bit Oracle Client library cannot
>   be loaded: "C:\Oracle\app\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin\oci.dll is not
>   the correct architecture". See
>   https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows for help

Can someone please help resolving the error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: What is version windows 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Either your PATH has some 32-bit Oracle libraries before any 64-bit libraries, or you don't actually have 64-bit Oracle libraries.

Comment: Dmitry - I have Windows 64 bit version.